# What does "walking to do" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does *walking to do* mean in the sentence below?

> They have 2 years and 7000 miles of walking to do.

Does the meaning changes if I omit *to do* or replace with *done*?

Comment: Should be 7000 **miles** of walking.

Comment: to have something to do: I have a lot of walking to do. I have a lot of studying to do. I have 2 years of studying to do.

Answer (score 5):

If you **have** something **to do**, then you have a task to complete.

*I can't go out tonight because I have a lot of homework to do.*

*My son had a party last night. We have a lot of cleaning up to do.*

*Peter must bury a dead dog. He has some digging to do.*

[Have something to do](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+(something)+to+do)

Answer (score 0):

"To do" means they will be walking in the future.  "Done" means they were walking in the past.